# Why doesn't junit run injected method?

Tags: java, spring, junit, javabeans, abstract

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract ClassA {

 protected abstract void method1 {...}
```

Another class ClassB that implements method1.

XML:

```
bean id="BaseBean" class="ClassB"

bean id="WorkBean" class="ClassA"
lookup-method="method1" bean="BaseBean"
```

in test:

```
$RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test.xml"
public class Test ....

@Autowired
private ClassA classA;
```

When I run test I receive error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError ....
```

Why? Seems that should be invoked method from BaseBean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is your problem, but BaseBean should have singleton="false" on it

Comment: in that case the theory of what you are trying to do should work.  its hard to tell without a more complete example

Comment: I suppose that spring cannot find method. I don't know why. Name the same. Is exists way to find why spring doesn't replaced abstract method?